# Angular 8 ng serve not loading app after upgraded from Angular 6 to 8

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I upgraded my angular from 6 to 8 with the command `ng update --all --force`. The upgraded was successful. When I do `ng serve` it also successfully serve as shown below
[image]

However, when i visit `localhost:4300`, it shows a blank page without any error in the browser console log. Here is my ng version 
[image]

My angular.jsonn

```html
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "lightsmind-website": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/browser",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "node_modules/angular2-toaster/toaster.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "src/assets/js/vendor/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "lightsmind-website:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "lightsmind-website:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "lightsmind-website:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "server": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/server",
            "main": "src/main.server.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.server.json"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "lightsmind-website-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "lightsmind-website:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "lightsmind-website:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "lightsmind-website"
}
```

My package.json

```html
{
  "name": "lightsmind-website",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "compile:server": "webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors",
    "serve:ssr": "node dist/server",
    "build:ssr": "npm run build:client-and-server-bundles && npm run compile:server",
    "build:client-and-server-bundles": "ng build --prod && ng run lightsmind-website:server:production",
    "build:ssr-firebase": "npm run build:ssr && npm --prefix functions/ run build"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^8.1.0-next.3",
    "@angular/common": "^8.1.0-next.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^8.1.0-next.3",
    "@angular/core": "^8.1.0-next.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^8.1.0-next.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^8.1.0-next.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.1.0-next.3",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^8.1.0-next.3",
    "@angular/router": "^8.1.0-next.3",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "8.2.6",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "8.2.6",
    "@types/braintree-web": "^3.47.1",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.2",
    "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.1",
    "angular2-toaster": "^8.0.0",
    "braintree-web": "^3.56.0",
    "core-js": "^3.6.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.2",
    "ng2-loading-spinner": "^1.3.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^5.2.0",
    "ngx-cookie": "^4.0.2",
    "ngx-pagination": "^5.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.3",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.21",
    "@angular/cli": "^8.3.21",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.1.0-next.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "^8.1.0-next.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "~12.12.21",
    "bufferutil": "^4.0.1",
    "codelyzer": "^5.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.2",
    "ts-loader": "^6.2.1",
    "ts-node": "~8.5.4",
    "tslint": "~5.20.1",
    "typescript": "3.5.3",
    "utf-8-validate": "^5.0.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10",
    "ws": "^7.2.1",
    "xhr2": "^0.2.0"
  }
}
```

My tsconfing.json

```html
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: `rm -r node modules`, `rm package-lock.json`, `npm cache clean -f`, `npm i`. This will clear out your dependencies and install them from scratch. If you get an error, that's the issue. When you do a force update, some packages dependencies might not be met. There is a good chance that's the problem. Not adding this as answer because there isn't nearly enough info to be sure. `ngx-....` are at a good risk of not being compatible across angular version.

Comment: using `--force` is never a good idea. Have you read the [update procedure](https://update.angular.io/#6.0:8.0)

Comment: Have you checked chrome console for errors?

Comment: @VSO i did exactly you said and still having the same issue. I resolved all the dependencies issus.

Comment: @Nicolas i actually followed the upgrade guide in https://update.angular.io/#6.0:8.0.

Comment: @Plochie - checked the chrome console and there is no errors.